# How to wrap text around table of contents

Tags: html, css

I am HTML programming newbie so I apologies if this question is too elementary.

I want to wrap the contents of an article around the table of contents. Here is my HTML web-page. That is I would like the table of contents to be on the left, and the article itself directly to start to the right of it.  If possible,   I would like to do this in a separate CSS file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
  <title>How to Win Friends and Influence People</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <h1 class="title">How to Win Friends and Influence People</h1>
    <div id="table-of-contents">
      <h2>Table of Contents</h2>
      <div id="text-table-of-contents">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#sec-1">1. Introduction</a></li>
          <li><a href="#sec-2">2. Section 2</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#sec-2-1">2.1. Subsection 3</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#sec-3">3. Section 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="outline-container-sec-1" class="outline-2">
      <h2 id="sec-1"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> Introduction</h2>
      <div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultrices arcu massa, vel euismod risus consequat eu. Vivamus vel magna sed est efficitur faucibus et id arcu. Sed facilisis arcu orci, non vulputate arcu gravida in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at neque a ante iaculis eleifend fermentum at tortor. Aliquam a mollis risus. Sed pharetra tempus eros ut posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean tempus elit nec nisi iaculis, sed convallis
          ipsum egestas. In condimentum mattis velit eget tincidunt. Nam at erat nec est hendrerit dignissim. Etiam orci diam, laoreet sit amet diam et, porttitor bibendum ante.
        </p>
        <div class="figure">
          <p><img src="test-asy.svg" alt="test-asy.svg" width="600" align="right" />
          </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultrices arcu massa, vel euismod risus consequat eu. Vivamus vel magna sed est efficitur faucibus et id arcu. Sed facilisis arcu orci, non vulputate arcu gravida in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
          amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at neque a ante iaculis eleifend fermentum at tortor. Aliquam a mollis risus. Sed pharetra tempus eros ut posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean tempus elit nec nisi iaculis, sed convallis
          ipsum egestas. In condimentum mattis velit eget tincidunt. Nam at erat nec est hendrerit dignissim. Etiam orci diam, laoreet sit amet diam et, porttitor bibendum ante.
        </p>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using css Flexbox or css floats.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="table-contents">
  <h3>
    Table of Contents
  </h3>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultrices arcu massa, vel euismod risus consequat eu. Vivamus vel magna sed est efficitur faucibus et id arcu. Sed facilisis arcu orci, non vulputate arcu gravida in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at neque a ante iaculis eleifend fermentum at tortor. Aliquam a mollis risus. Sed pharetra tempus eros ut posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean tempus elit nec nisi iaculis, sed convallis ipsum egestas. In condimentum mattis velit eget tincidunt. Nam at erat nec est hendrerit dignissim. Etiam orci diam, laoreet sit amet diam et, porttitor bibendum ante.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.table-contents, .content{
  padding: 10px;
}

.table-contents{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wkszuvLm/1/ 
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`body` tag is already there wrapping around everything, you could use it as well as adding another `div` inside `body` to wrap everything else.
There are multiple ways to place elements within a container. Learn about using `css` `display` property set to `grid` or `flex`. Both come with their own subset of properties.
use `link` tag to use an external css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file_url_here">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by putting those in two different `div` and then style them as required.

```
.divLeft {
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
.divRight {
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
}
```

You can put the above in `css` file and call in your `<head>` tag or you can also use it as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>How to Win Friends and Influence People</title>
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.divLeft {
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}
.divRight {
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div class="divLeft">
<h1 class="title">How to Win Friends and Influence People</h1>
<div id="table-of-contents">
<h2>Table of Contents</h2>
<div id="text-table-of-contents">
<ul>
<li><a href="#sec-1">1. Introduction</a></li>
<li><a href="#sec-2">2. Section 2</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#sec-2-1">2.1. Subsection 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#sec-3">3. Section 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="divRight">
<div id="outline-container-sec-1" class="outline-2">
<h2 id="sec-1"><span class="section-number-2">1</span> Introduction</h2>
<div class="outline-text-2" id="text-1">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultrices arcu massa, vel euismod risus consequat eu. Vivamus vel magna sed est efficitur faucibus et id arcu. Sed facilisis arcu orci, non vulputate arcu gravida in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at neque a ante iaculis eleifend fermentum at tortor. Aliquam a mollis risus. Sed pharetra tempus eros ut posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean tempus elit nec nisi iaculis, sed convallis ipsum egestas. In condimentum mattis velit eget tincidunt. Nam at erat nec est hendrerit dignissim. Etiam orci diam, laoreet sit amet diam et, porttitor bibendum ante.
</p>

<div class="figure">
<p><img src="test-asy.svg" alt="test-asy.svg" width="600" align="right" />
</p>
</div>


<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ultrices arcu massa, vel euismod risus consequat eu. Vivamus vel magna sed est efficitur faucibus et id arcu. Sed facilisis arcu orci, non vulputate arcu gravida in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at neque a ante iaculis eleifend fermentum at tortor. Aliquam a mollis risus. Sed pharetra tempus eros ut posuere. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean tempus elit nec nisi iaculis, sed convallis ipsum egestas. In condimentum mattis velit eget tincidunt. Nam at erat nec est hendrerit dignissim. Etiam orci diam, laoreet sit amet diam et, porttitor bibendum ante.
</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```